# Ruby:concatenate pairs of strings in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

Given the array

```
["zone", "abigail", "theta", "form", "libe", "zas"]
```

Is there a straightforward way to go through the array and combine the strings into pairs, thus...

```
["zoneabigail", "abigailtheta", "thetaform", "formlibe", "libezas"]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are searching for [`Enumerable#each_cons`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons):

```
words.each_cons(2).map(&:join)
```

Comment: This is really good - works well. I apologise for not giving my attempts. My issue is that I didn't know where to start. This gives me something to study.

Comment: @GhostRider happy to help.